# Integration of Jupyter Notebook with Keycloak

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, keycloak, jupyterhub, keycloak-services

Is it possible to use Keycloak with Jupyter Notebook to sign in users? I am currently using signing in to Jupyter Notebooks with a password, for which I used the configuration file, but I need to switch to Keycloak.

I know that it is possible to integrate JupyterHub and Keycloak, and I did it using the existing instructions in the documentation. Are there some instructions for Jupyter Notebook too?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your question resembles [this one at the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/run-jupyter-notebook-in-kubernetes-protected-with-keycloak-gatekeeper/5349?u=fomightez). Unfortunately, there hasn't been a reply yet. You may wish to add your version to that thread in hopes of getting a response by those that may know more?